# Firebase cloud functions compress video

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have successfully implemented video sharing in my app using react native and firebase, but I want to ensure videos being stored are no more than 1080x1080 (maybe 720 depending how it looks).

Videos are max 8 seconds long, I am trying my best to keep them under 5MB each if possible. I was able to do some compressing on the client side (crop to square/trim), but I am hoping to be able to compress the videos even more without losing that quality via cloud functions (storage trigger).

After doing some looking around, it looks like [Moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html?highlight=resize#moviepy.video.fx.all.resize) is a good option, but it use's python and I am not sure how I can use this script inside of a cloud function storage trigger.

Here is what that looks like:

```
//Not sure how this will import
import moviepy.editor as mp

//Can I get the video here from the bucket path in a cloud function?
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("video-stored.mp4")

clip_resized = clip.resize(height=1080) # make the height 1080px ( According to moviePy documenation The width is then computed so that the width/height ratio is conserved.)

//resize video, then we need to store it in the same location (same file path)
clip_resized.write_videofile("video-stored-resized.mp4")
```

I would love to hear some suggestions regarding video compressing via a cloud function and thoughts on using the above script/module with cloud functions.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks Doug, question edited.

Comment: I'm in the same scenario, just found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149078/firebase-cloud-functions-using-python I didn't try yet.

Comment: What solution did you end up going with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, firebase functions does not support languages other than node.js.
Thus, there are 2 solutions.

1. if you would like to keep using moviepy.
   Writing a part to call moviepy-related apis when firebase storage is triggered in node.js and having the python api in any preferred environments. (I guess you should use pubsub provided by gcp to call the python apis)
2. writing all parts in node.js
   There is a great module called fluent-ffmepg in node.js too but I know adding a watermark with the module is not as easy as moviepy is...

By the way, when I tried to combine vids in firebase functions, I was not able to make it maybe because of the limitation of the environment.
So, I personally recommend the very first solution: ofc it depends on your situation such as how big your video files are.