# iOS push notifications with Firebase FCM to a specific user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send notifications to users when something happens in their account, for example a new friend request or follower, or a tag in an image. I have been looking into Firebase FCM to make this happen but can't figure out how to send push notifications to just 1 user, based on some activity in their account.

Is there any way this can be done in FCM or are there are any other methods out there to make this happen? I'm new to iOS dev and push notifications, so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

PS: If I do need to make my own server for this, could someone point me to any resources to do this in python? I've seen quite a few posts for APNs servers in PHP, but I don't know PHP that well.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - sending a messages is covered in the [Firebase Cloud Messaging Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) which also includes an overview of  [Sending a test message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message) to a specific device. Have you written some code and are having a specific coding issue, which is what SO is for?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) , I have experience working with it using Javascript then trigger the function when something changes in database. You can also send a http request with the specific device token which you want a push notification to be delivered to, then the function will do it's magic for you. Firebase have ready to use samples from their [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

NB: - For your case if you really want to use Python then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149226/7551807) it might help you get started.